# how to enable ownership of all devices?

Tags: chown

The Linux security goes OVERBOARD  when
there is a single user , hardware never to be accessed by public , strictly home operation.

Adding simple USB flash drive turns into exercise in futility...
Activating NEW partition on EXISTING HDD same...

PLEASE help.
Thanks

Comment: You may need chown & chmod. Example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/324705/first-full-backup-on-usb-permission-denied/324942#324942

Comment: Unfortunately, your question currently is difficult to answer because you don't state a specific task you are trying to accomplish, and what environment (Linux distribution, graphical or command-line interface ...) you are trying to use. Please edit your question to add more details, so that contributors can help you with a defined problem.

Comment: how to enable ownership of all devices? "enable ownership of all devices " . This is Linux forum, is it not ? The only contributor having difficulty is you...

Answer (score 1):

It very much depends on your distro, but the standard way is to add your user to the unix group that the device is in.

For my distro (Devuan), I added myself to `audio`, `video`, `plugdev`, `netdev`, `input`, `fuse` and `media`. What **you** need to do depends on your distro and the software you have installed.

Also, add yourself to `sudoers`, and do all administrative tasks with `sudo`. That's standard practice and prevents you from accidentally destroying things.

---

> I can plug in new USB Flash Drive

Then the kernel + udev will detect it as an USB storage device, it'll get a device node `/dev/sd[a-z]` for the device itself, and more nodes for partitions on it, and those devices belong to the group `disk` (which I actually forgot to mention above). Moreover, my automounter will mount it somewhere to `/media/`, giving FAT filesystems permissions for my user.

> At that point I have no knowledge about /dev/???

You do. And if the kernel cannot find some modules that creates devices in `/dev` for you, you likely won't be able to do *anything* with that USB device.

> I am using Linux and what flavor and in case of CLI, it should not matter

But it does matter.

> Is CLI pretty much same for all flavors?

Yes, but device creation works via [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev), and each distro makes up its own rules and groups. It'll look differently under, say, Red Hat compared to Debian.

I can understand that you want to work Linux differently from the way it works. But wishful thinking won't make it work the way you like. So stop doing that, and learn what it really does.

Comment: Let me present an example -  I can plug in new USB Flash Drive . Then  I verify it using "lsusb". At that point I have no knowledge about /dev/??? Hence "no group it belongs to "... What is my next choice - GUI or CLI  - does not matter. I am using Linux and what flavor and in case of CLI. it should not matter . (Is CLI pretty much same for all flavors?)